# How to open a child window in Electron with Vuejs

Tags: electron, vuejs2

I am using this package https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/ to use Electron and Vuejs together. So the documentation for some things in Electron does not work.

I want to open a child browser window using a button in a component.

In the component methods: I have this code from the Electron docs:

```
openWindow () {

    let child = new BrowserWindow({parent: top, modal: true, show: false})
    child.loadURL('https://github.com')
    child.once('ready-to-show', () => {
      child.show()
    })

  }
```

But when I hit my button it says:

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_electron__.BrowserWindow is not a constructor
at VueComponent.openWindow
```

Comment: Where is openWIndow? In your renderer?

Comment: In my component "methods:"

Comment: So, in your renderer. Do you import BrowserWindow?

Comment: Yeah I did ....

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post. But I too recently came across this. For those of you now experiencing this too you have to import BrowserWindow using remote

```
const electron = require('electron').remote
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
```

[Here is a post explaining it a bit in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639628/how-to-fix-browserwindow-is-not-a-constructor-error-when-creating-child-window-i)

Comment: `remote` is deprecated