# How to fix BrowserWindow is not a constructor error when creating child window in Electron renderer process

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm using electron to build an application that includes two windows. I'm trying to open a second window from inside renderer process doing something like:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

const childWindow = new BrowserWindow({
   width: 800,
   height: 600
});
```

I'm getting an error saying

> BrowserWindow is not a constructor.

My other option is to use window.open, but that is not ideal since that returns BrowserWindowProxy object, which has limited functionality.

Comment: I fixed my own problem by including electron.remote.BrowserWindow instead. https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/remote/

Comment: You should consider providing a full self-answer since you found a solution to your problem.

Comment: Just added a full self-answer, thank you!

Answer (score 56):

I found that all I needed to do was to use the `remote` module. 
Electron doesn't allow to directly create a browser window from the renderer process, because it (BrowserWindow) requires `ipc` module to communicate with the main process. Electron documentation says:

> In Electron, GUI-related modules (such as dialog, menu etc.) are only available in the main process, not in the renderer process. In order to use them from the renderer process, the ipc module is necessary to send inter-process messages to the main process.

So, `new electron.BrowserWindow()` doesn't work.
However, using `remote` module correctly sets up inter-process communicating with the main process and the following modified code works for me:

```js
const electron = require('electron');
const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow;

const childWindow = new BrowserWindow({
   width: 800,
   height: 600
});
```

A more complete explanation of `remote` module is here: https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/remote/

Comment: I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'BrowserWindow' of undefined using your above code

Answer (score 10):

For anyone that also has this problem and their code isn't inside an electron renderer, you're probably running the script using `node script.js`, you need to run it using `electron script.js`.

Comment: This should be the top comment, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I kept running into a related error with being able to access the `dialog` module in my renderer processes. I ended up following the guide on this webpage, which does it through ipc: https://developpaper.com/using-electron-to-call-up-the-system-dialog-box/